# Trouble converting excel data to currency in Microsoft Power Automate

Tags: excel, automation, power-automate

I have a column in my excel file called 'Prices' that contains all the data I need to populate my HTML table. problem is, when using the formatNumber() function i get the following error.

My input:

**formatNumber(item()?['Prices'], 'C2','en-US')** - 'The template language function 'formatNumber' expects its first parameter to be an integer or a decimal number. The provided value is of type 'String'.

I've tried to cast it to a int and a float but had no luck.

Wondering if anyone has any input that could help....

Cheers.

Comment: Try putting “FormatNumber(int(item()?['Prices']), 'C2','en-US')” When reading from Excel, it doesn’t know that it is a number, so by using the int() expression, you can convert the string to a number.

Comment: @Ethan, hey man thanks for responding. I wound up trying that yesterday as well as float but ran into this issue: 'The template language function 'int' was invoked with a parameter that is not valid. The value cannot be converted to the target type.'.

Comment: Try int(substring())